# ASP.NET WebForms read IDToken after Azure Active Directory authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, openid

I have an old **webforms** asp.net web application, based on **Identity 2.0** local authentication that I have to upgrade to allow also the authentication for external users registered in the **Azure Active Directory** of the company.

I'm able to run the challenge and get back the users on the web page after they authenticate on Microsoft, but I'm not able to read any info of the user. In example, I want to know their email in order to let them enter my application or register as new users.
I expect to have this information in the token, but how can I access it server-side?

Here is my code:

```
    public partial class Startup {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager,User>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
                    OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
                    {
                       ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);                      
                    }
                }
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);           

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
                Authority = "https://login.windows.net/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44364/testlogin.aspx",
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
                // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
                // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter 
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                },
                // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }

            }
            );

        }

        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("~/TestLogin.aspx?ErrorMessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
```

and here is the call to login external active directory users:

```
Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
      new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "~/TestLogin.aspx" },
      OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

and finally in the TestLogin.aspx page where I try to read information about the logged in users:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated) //Always False!
{
    Label1.Text = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("name").Value;
}

var userClaims = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
if (userClaims != null) //It's not null but there is no information about the email of the logged in user
{
    Label1.Text += userClaims?.FindFirst("name")?.Value; //It's empty
}
```

How can I **read** the **claims** returned by active directory in the **ID Token**?

**UPDATE**

If I remove the option in the cookie authentication, Azure Active Directory works, but I'm not able anymore to sign in local users:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
     AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
     LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
     Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
      {
              OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager,User>(
              validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
              regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
              OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
              {
                  ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);                      
              }
        }
});
```

into this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
```

Is there a way to make them both works?

Comment: Have you tried to use the following code ```var userClaims = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity; Label1.Text=userClaims?.FindFirst("name")?.Value;```?

Comment: @JimXu Nothing. It's always null

Comment: What do you mean local user?

Comment: Users that are saved in the AspNetUsers table of the database of the application